# Get PathInfo from RenderRequest

Tags: java, portlet

I need to get `pathInfo` from `portlet` - `RenderRequest`.
On the documentation - [portlet doc's](https://cocoon.apache.org/2.1/apidocs/org/apache/cocoon/environment/portlet/PortletRequest.html#getPathInfo()) the method `getPathInfo` should return the String I need but :

```
    @Override
    protected String setRenderData(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response) {
        super.setRenderData(request, response);
        request.getPathInfo(); //The method getPathInfo() is undefined for the type RenderRequest
     }
```

The method is undefiend.

I also tried to cast the request to `PortletRequest`:

```
    PortletRequest preq = (PortletRequest) request;
    preq.getPathInfo(); // The method getPathInfo() is undefined for the type PortletRequest
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're tagging [java](/questions/tagged/java) and [portlet](/questions/tagged/portlet), I'm assuming that you're referring to JSR-286, the Java portlet spec. This, in turn, leads to [`javax.portlet.PortletRequest`](https://portals.apache.org/pluto/portlet-2.0-apidocs/javax/portlet/PortletRequest.html) and not `org.apache.cocoon.environment.portlet.PortletRequest`, that you are linking to. Assuming this is your environment (correct me if you're indeed using cocoon), here's your reason for the method not being available.

And as you don't give any hint what you'd like to use this information for (e.g. what's the problem you're trying to solve with this data), the answer has to end here. You're just looking up the wrong Javadoc.